# When set the background with a selector,it cause resouce not found

Tags: android, layout, selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellay_action_bar_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/blue" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_action_bar_left"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_back"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_action_bar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_action_bar_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_action_bar_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/rellay_action_bar_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout where cause the problem.`"android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_action_bar_right"`"
this view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="false"></item>

</selector>
```

and this is the selector

> 04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.yuanpaiapp.yuanpai.android/com.yuanpaiapp.yuanpai.android.activity.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error
>   inflating class  04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class  04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   com.yuanpaiapp.yuanpai.android.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:29)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   ... 11 more 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     ... 25 more 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556): Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-mdpi-v4/selector_btn_action_bar_right.xml from drawable
>   resource ID #0x7f020019 04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):
>     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3330) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:583) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:103) 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   ... 28 more 04-26 01:30:01.550:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1556): Caused by:
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: 
>   tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
>   04-26 01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950) 04-26
>   01:30:01.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1556):     ... 33 more

Answer (score 1):

Use **drawable** instead of **color** .

There two optional methods,

- Using **shape** in selector

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
          <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:shape="rectangle" >
              <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
          </shape>
      </item>
      <item >
          <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:shape="rectangle" >
              <solid android:color="@color/white" />
          </shape>
      </item>
  </selector>
  ```
- Using **picture** in selector

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue" android:state_pressed="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" android:state_pressed="false" />
  </selector>
  ```

Comment: I think I need to correct my question.I need to change the textcolor of the button.the reason I don't use the textview is that I want expand the coverage of the view.What should I do in the case?or? you have some other solution?please?

Comment: yes, you may use the attr **padding** to expand the coverage.